# The autoregressive model is a particularity of class general ARIMA?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

I'm social science student and recently started studyng time series.

My question is if the autoregressive model is a particularity of class general ARIMA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is basically AR(P) = ARIMA(P, $0$, $0$)